# Netgear Prosafe SRX5308 config with Virgin Superhub

Tags: router, mac-address, modem, netgear

We have just bought a Netgear Prosafe SRX5308 to provide load balancing with our 4 internet connections, but I am struggling to get it configured with our Virgin Media connection.

The auto-detect feature in the SRX5308 does not appear to work, so I have entered the settings manually. I have set the Virgin Media username and password in the WAN settings options, set the connection type to PPPoE, and left the IP address to be dynamically assigned but this does not seem to connect.

I have also tried to use the Virgin Media SuperHub's MAC address in the advanced tab of the SRX5308 (as suggested in this post: https://community.netgear.com/t5/VPN-Firewalls/FVS336Gv3-with-Virgin-SuperHub-2/td-p/512689) but this appears to make no difference.

Has anyone successfully got these two working together?